# "Property console is not allowed" Problem in VSC Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to debug my cpp program in Visual Studio Code in ubuntu 20.00. Hence,I'm facing to following problem:

```
{
    "resource": "/home/xxx/Desktop/Project/.vscode/launch.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Property console is not allowed.",
    "startLineNumber": 17,
    "startColumn": 13,
    "endLineNumber": 17,
    "endColumn": 22
}
```

That's my launch.json file:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

I wonder how I handle this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `"console": "externalTerminal"` with `"externalTerminal" : true` if you would like your code to execute in a external console window. Otherwise remove the line completly